# Is there such a thing as inline bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to do something on the lines of:

```
find -name *.mk | xargs "for i in $@ do mv i i.aside end"
```

I realize that there might be more than on error in this, but I'd like to specifically know about this sort of inline command definition that I can pass xargs to.

Comment: so you want to simply rename all the *.mk files or something else?

Comment: On what OS are you? At least Linux knows the `rename` command, check out http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: You should remember that `find` and `xargs` are really nothing to do with bash, they are independant programs.  They don't know (or care) about bash commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need for xargs here

`find -name *.mk -exec mv {} {}.aside \;`

Comment: Q:"How do I do X?". A:"You don't need to do X"

Answer (score 8):

This particular command isn't a great example, but you can use an "inline shell script" by giving `sh -c 'here is the script'` as a command. And you can give it arguments which will be $@ inside the script but there's a catch: the first argument after `here is the script` goes to $0 inside the script, so you have to put an extra word there or you'll lose the first argument.

```
find . -name '*.mk' -exec sh -c 'for i; do mv "$i" "$i.aside"; done' fnord '{}' +
```

Another fun feature I took advantage of there is the fact that for loops iterate over the command line arguments by default: `for i; do ...` is equivalent to `for i in "$@"; do ...`

I reiterate, the above command is convoluted and slow compared to the many other methods of doing the bulk mv. I'm posting it only to show some cool syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the semantics of your for loop should be, but blindly coding it would give something like this:

```
find -name *.mk | while read file
  do
    for i in $file; do mv $i $i.aside; done
  done
```

If the body is used in multiple places, you can also use bash functions.

Answer (score 0):

In some version of find an argument is needed : . for the current directory

Star * must be escaped

You can try with echo command to be sure what command will do

```
find . -name '*.mk' -print0 | xargs -0i sh -c "echo mv '{}' '{}.aside'" 
man xargs
/-i
man sh
/-c
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you could do this in a nice manner, but since you requested xargs:

```
find -name "*.tk" | xargs -I% mv % %.aside
```

Looping over filenames makes no sense, since you can only rename one at a time. Using inline uglyness is not necessary, but I could not make it work with the pipe and either `eval` or `bash -c`.